# How to convert embedded string array into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, string-parsing

I have an array coming in string format.  How do i convert it to an array.

```
my_data="['A','B','C']"  (Note the quotes around [])
convert this to ['A','B','C']
```

So far i tried json.parse and other string to array conversations without luck.  Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Remove extra characters and split by comma.

Comment: agree, but instead of string manipulation, there may be a way to convert this string into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the single quotes with double quotes using regex, then JSON.parse will work fine: `JSON.parse(my_data.replace(/\'/g,"\""));`

Single quotes are not valid characters for JSON data.

Comment: It worked.  you are right, single quotes seems to be a problem.